# Multi-objective optimisation in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have two objectives to be maximised in ArcMap. One is wind speed and other is distance to residentials. I have the maps of wind speed and distance to residentials.

Is it possible to compare pixel 1 and pixel 2 and find if pixel 2 dominates or has better wind speed and distance to residentials?

If so pixel 2 will be eliminated. Likewise, I want to compare pixel 3 with pixel 4, pixel 5 with pixel 6 and all pixels in the study area.

Comment: I suggest you take Esri's course on the Spatial Analyst extension